# How to get an Optional type as a response from RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, option-type, resttemplate

I have two spring applications running. One makes a call to an api in the other app using RestTemplate. The return type of this api is `Optional<User>`. The calling app uses the below method to make the call:

```
restTemplate.getForObject(path, Optional.class)
```

While debugging, I see that the api is returning the object properly, but somehow my calling app is getting a null response body.
So, I tried updating the return type of the api to `User` and the calling code to : `restTemplate.getForObject(path, User.class)` and it works fine.

I need to know how to get an Optional response type using RestTemplate. I'm, not sure what is it that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can use getForEntity and on ResponseEntity you can verify the status code and get the body. You can use hasBody method from ResponseEntity to verify if body exists.

Comment: You don't. As when it is empty you will get a NOT_FOUND (404) else you get a 200. So what the return type on the server is doesn't mean has to be the return value on the client!.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your own RestTemplate class extending the existing `RestTemplate` class which provides a method returning an optional of the expected response type.

Following I've provided a small example showing a way you could implement it:

```
public class FooRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {
    public <T> Optional<T> getForObjectAsOptional(final URI url, Class<T> responseType) throws RestClientException {
        try {
            return Optional.ofNullable(super.getForObject(url, responseType));
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
            logger.error("Error: ", ex);
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a simple example.
You could also extend the catch block. For example return `Optional.empty()` only  if the status code equals 404 not found:

```
public class FooOptionalEmptyNotFoundRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {
    public <T> Optional<T> getForObjectAsOptional(final URI url, Class<T> responseType) throws RestClientException {
        try {
            return Optional.ofNullable(super.getForObject(url, responseType));
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {                
            if(ex.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)) {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
            
            logger.error("Error: ", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```